# How do I display multiple divs (and their child elements) as Inline?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to display 4 div sections side by side by setting the parent div to:

```
.parent {
    display: inline;
}
```

```
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <ul>
                <li>test1</li>
                <li>test1</li>
                <li>test1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="child">
            <ul>
                <li>test1</li>
                <li>test1</li>
                <li>test1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="child">
            <ul>
                <li>test1</li>
                <li>test1</li>
                <li>test1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The 4 divs (with child elements nested) remain stacked as block elements:

```
test1
test1
test1
test1
test1
test1
test1
test1
test1
```

But I want them side by side like this - test1 test1 test1

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
.parent .child {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Please use this reference for further details: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.parent .child li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. You can try flexbox:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```